# How to open a pre-saved text file (.txt) using word editor(.docx) directly from R console in R studio?

Tags: r

I have the results file saved in .txt format. I wish to open that text file in Word document directly from the R console. If I copy paste the following command (winword "C:\Users\results.txt") in windows command prompt I was able to open the text file in the word document.  However, I want to open this directly from the R console.

```
x = paste0('"','C:\\Users\\results.txt', '"')

system(x)

shell.exec(x)

shell(x)
```

Open the text using Word directly from R console.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried running that command with `system`?

Comment: I tried shell.exec(winword "C:\Users\results.txt") . And I created a character x (address of the .txt file) and used the command shell.exec(x)

Comment: Maybe `x <- paste('winword', '"C:/Users/results.txt"')`.

Comment: You open a txt document in Word or any other editor. You don't open a text file "in Word document".  I suspect the actual question is how to control Word from R? You'd have to use COM for this. `paste0` is irrelevant. The only reason pasting the file's path, or `shell.exec` works is because in **your** computer, the application associated with the `txt` extension is Word. On my machine the same code would start Sublime Text.

Comment: @Rui Barradas. I get the following error:  Error in shell.exec(x) : 
  'winword "C:/Users/results.txt"' not found

Comment: Try without the double quotes around the filename.

Comment: @divibisanI tried running with system but it didn't work.

Comment: @Rui Barradas I tried without the double quotes but it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You can read text in the R console (similar to a document) with the `readtext` package

```
library(readtext)

my.text = readtext("file_path/text_file.txt")
my.text$text
```

Comment: The asker doesn't want to read text, they want to open a file in Microsoft Word from inside R (for some reason)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I misunderstood.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to save the output directly in word document. I wasn't able to do that. So I first saved the output from console in .txt file using the sink command and then from the command prompt i used the command winword "C:\users\results.txt" to open in word editor.